# Nexus 4 - NFC AAR and Filter

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, android-applicationrecord

I'm writing the Static Handover Select Record on a Tag with the Wifi Protected Setup Configuration as specified in the NFC Forum. (SSID, Encryption, ...).

The type is `application/vnd.wfa.wsc`

Additionally I add the Android Application Record as last NDEF Record into my NDEF Message.

I also have a filter defined in my Android Manifest XML for NFC Tags discovered.

The problem is: If the application is launched and the Reader Activity is shown, I can read the tag and everything works fine.

Now I want the following:
If I scan my Tag, and the activity isn't @ foreground or not launched, the app should start itself and switch automatically into the reader mode.

1. If I do that, the Nexus 4 doesn't launch by the AAR... It just starts, if i put this Record on the first place of the NDEF Message, but then I loose the event for the Ndef/Tech/Tag discovered.
2. I also have the filter in my android manififest, but this seems not to do anything, I tried all three events but nothing happens

Also, if the Tag is scanned, normally if more applications are filtering for the event, I get a app-selector, which app I want to start for this Tag. But my application is not listed here.

This is how I create the message:

```
new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { Utils.createHandoverSelectRecord(ac_record.toByteArray()), wpsRecord, aarRecord });
```

And here is the filter in my android manifest:

```
  <activity android:name=".activities.NFCWriterActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.NFCReaderActivity" android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.NFC">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>        
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.NFCBeamActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WifiManagerActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WifiConfiguratorActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.TagWriterOptionsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WifiScannerTagActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WifiScannerActivity"></activity> 
        <activity android:name=".activities.WifiListActivity"></activity>  

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
             <!--  <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wfa.wsc" /> -->
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>                                
        </activity>       

    </application>
```

I don't really know where I should filter, I thought it would be enough to filter in the Reader Activity, but this didn't work, so I added the filters also in the MainActivity, but this also does nothing.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an intent filter that exactly matches the MIME type of the first NDEF record:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wfa.wsc" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: The first record is a Handover Select, the second one is the application/vnd.wfa.wsc. I solved the problem now under the LG Nexus 4 by adding the complete Techlist to the intent-filter as given on the developers site. But the AAR-Record is completely ignored if it is not on the first place of the NDEF-message.. But on this position I cannot need it. But the entry must be correct because I scanned the TAG with an app of NXP an it shows me the 3 NDEF-messages and the AAR is correctly linked to my application... Some idea why the AAR doesn't work?

Comment: With the Handover Select as the first record, Android will handle the message itself and not pass it on to an app. However, currently it only has support for Handover to Bluetooth. Apps cannot filter for Handover Select messages (it is a Well-Known Type record; there is no syntax to handle those with intent filters).